# Recoding Dataset with multiple decoder dataframes r

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, data-wrangling

I have dataset

```
structure(list(animal = c("dg", "dg", "c", "c", "dg", "eph", 
"eph"), water = c("y", "n", "n", "y", "n", "y", "n"), temperature = c(77, 
72, 88, 88, 49, 59, 76)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```

The data is currently coded. The only way to decode this dataframe is using 2 dataframes in conjunction. ​

First use this dataframe to find the column name that is in original dataset `var_name` and check what the coded variable name is `code_name`.

```
structure(list(Var_name = c("animal", "water", "temperature"), 
    Code_name = c("ani2", "h20", NA)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Once you have the coded variable name `code_name` you go to this dataset

```
structure(list(code_name = c("ani2", "ani2", "ani2", "h20", "h20"
), coded_value = c("dg", "c", "eph", "y", "n"), decoded_value = c("dog", 
"cat", "elephant", "yes", "no")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

And convert the original dataframe's values in the `coded_value` column to the `decoded_value`. What are the optimal ways to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

If the 3 dataframes that you have shared are called `df1`, `df2` and `df3` respectively and assuming that if a column name has `NA` as `Code_name` in `df2` you want to keep the original values as it is (for `temperature` column).

We can first use `match` to get corresponding code values from `df2` then use `Map` to get the `decoded_value` for each column.

```
code_values <- df2$Code_name[match(names(df1), df2$Var_name)]

df1[] <- Map(function(x, y) {
  if(is.na(y)) return(x)
  tmp <- subset(df3, code_name == y)
  tmp$decoded_value[match(x, tmp$coded_value)]
}, df1, code_values)
df1

#    animal water temperature
#1      dog   yes          77
#2      dog    no          72
#3      cat    no          88
#4      cat   yes          88
#5      dog    no          49
#6 elephant   yes          59
#7 elephant    no          76
```

Comment: Just curious, what would happen in this case if there is a column in df1 that does not exist in df2 or df3 as a decoded option? Would it delete all the values inside? Is there a way around that?

Comment: No change is needed if column name is not present in `df2` but if the decoded values are absent in `df3` this answer would return `NA`'s for them. To maintain the same value change the line `tmp$decoded_value[match(x, tmp$coded_value)]` to `dplyr::coalesce(tmp$decoded_value[match(x, tmp$coded_value)], x)` @rj44

Comment: Gotcha! Is there a way to expand this further by coercing incompatible vector types?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

To get all information in one dataframe you could combine joins: Assuming dataframes are called df1, df2, df3 in your presented order:

```
library(dplyr)

df_result <- df1 %>% 
  left_join(df3, by= c("animal" = "coded_value")) %>% 
  right_join(df2, by= c("code_name" = "Code_name"))
```

Output:

```
  animal water temperature code_name decoded_value    Var_name
1     dg     y          77      ani2           dog      animal
2     dg     n          72      ani2           dog      animal
3      c     n          88      ani2           cat      animal
4      c     y          88      ani2           cat      animal
5     dg     n          49      ani2           dog      animal
6    eph     y          59      ani2      elephant      animal
7    eph     n          76      ani2      elephant      animal
8   <NA>  <NA>          NA       h20          <NA>       water
9   <NA>  <NA>          NA      <NA>          <NA> temperature
```

Comment: this option is okay, but is cumbersome when expanded to a massive dataset with many columns that need to be decoded.